# Reading out address numbers

Tags: speaking

In the Ana Pana course, Ana pronounces her house number 1234 as "*mil ducent tridek kvar*". In English, I would not say "I live at one thousand two hundred thirty-four Long Street", I would say "one two three four" or "twelve thirty-four". It seems that "*dek du tridek kvar*" could be confusing, but what about "*unu du tri kvar*"? Is that an acceptable way of reading an address number? Ana's way becomes especially cumbersome if you have more digits in the number; if I live at 54321 Nowhere Road; must I say "*kvindek kvar mil tricent dudek unu*", or can I simply say "*kvin kvar tri du unu*"? Are there any official rules on this?

Comment: Isn't this valid also for numbers that are not part of an address? In American, they say _nineteen eighty_ for 1980.

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be a precedent, at least for small numbers, to read out the number including the place values:

- Ĝi troviĝas ĉi tie, en la ĉambro tricent tridek kvar.

Additional examples are here:

http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/nombroj/vortetoj/uzado.html

This doesn't seem to apply to telephone numbers, which are read out as individual digits.

- ok nulo nulo, kvin kvin kvin, unu du, tri kvar.

Answer (score 4):

All of these are viable because an address is less of an actual number for counting and more of a special name used for lookup purposes. In everyday conversation I would suggest either dek du tridek kvar or unu du tri kvar. This is because your mind remembers things better in chunks- it's a lot easier to remember a phone number as 847 555 3422 than as 8475553422

Comment: "an address is less an actual number for counting and more of a special name used for lookup purposes" — that's what I was thinking; it's not even like they start at one end of the road and count "1, 2, 3, ...  54321"; the numbers are influenced by things like cross-street numbers, as well as whatever the powers that be felt like doing, so it's not even literally the 54321st house.

Comment: @kristan That depends _a lot_ on the country. In many European countries (including here in the Netherlands), you _do_ start from house number 1, and so on down the street. (But with steps of 2, because it's usually odd numbers on one side and even numbers on the other.) So if on one end of the street you see house number 213, there are usually actually about 213 houses along the street, if not more. This combined with city planning that often evolved over centuries also means that our streets generally never even get close to numbers like 1234, and many people live at numbers below 100.